# TypeError: notes.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Доброе время суток

пишу простой проект на React и столкнулся с такой проблемой

**TypeError: notes.map is not a function**

Перепробовал много решении как с stackoverflow так и другиех сайтов, но ошибка не пропадает

вот мой код

```
import React from 'react'
import {notes} from "../data/data.js";

export const Notes = ({notes}) => {
return (
    <ul className="list-group">
        {notes.map(note => (
            <li 
            className="list-group-item note"
            key={id}
            >
                <strong>{title}</strong>
                <span>{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</span>
                <button 
                type="button"
                className='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm'
                >
                    &times;
                </button>
            </li>   
        ))}
    </ul>
```

файл data.js

```
import React from 'react';  

export const notes = () => { 
new Array ( {arrayLength: 3})
    .fill({value:""})
    .map({calbackfh: (_, i) => ({id: i, title: "Note ${i+1}"})});
 }

 export default notes;
```

Прошу не бросать сразу камни типа - иди учи тотариал

Использую

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
```

Comment: `notes` это функция.А `map` создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента ВНИМАНИЕ __массива__.

Comment: 1. notes надо вызвать чтобы по нему пробежаться => notes().map
2.из notes надо вернуть массив чтобы по нему пробежаться ==> return new Array
3.и в porps и в import имена совпадают как js должен понять по кому пробежаться